# Can we integrate slack with JIRA, without having JIRA's admin access?

Tags: slack, chatops

Can we integrate slack with JIRA, without having JIRA's admin access?
I want to create issues from JIRA but dont have admin access in the same.

Comment: I don't know either way, but if you could, that'd surely be a _massive_ security flaw, which leads me to think, no.

Comment: Okay.. I was thinking the same, but was wondering if a user can do using their own credentials in just the board/project created by them.

Answer (score 0):

So what I got is, it is something not allowed yet. One needs to be JIRA admin to do the stuff.